# Windows Batch: How can I use a for /f loop to find specific values of something?

Tags: cmd

How can I use a `for /f` loop to find specific values of something? Let's say I want to find "Myprocess.exe" and only print its PID. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
tasklist | Findstr /c:"MyProcess.exe"
```

Is one way